# Update textarea rows via Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to adjust the number of rows in a textArea on focus on remove them on blur. In addition upon focus I want to show a hidden div layer. My current solution is

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="1" placeholder="Please enter text..." 
onfocus="this.rows=3" ng-focus="isVisible = !isVisible" onblur="this.rows=1" 
ng-blur="isVisible = !isVisible"></textarea>
```

As you can see from above I have to use two attributes, i.e. HTML onfocus to increase the rows and ng-focus to update isVisible (to show and hide the div). It works, but I was wondering if it's possible to increase and decrease the number of rows using ng-focus and ng-blur only.

Div layer I am showing and hiding

```
<div class="row" ng-show="isVisible" />
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically you could use `ng-attr-rows` to set `rows` attribute value dynamically. You could have something like below.

Basically on each digest cycle [**`ng-attr-*`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#-ngattr-for-binding-to-arbitrary-attributes) directive evaluate its expression, in your case `*` is `rows`, and add that evaluated value to rows attribute.

**Markup**

```
<textarea ng-model="test" 
   ng-attr-rows="{{row || '1'}}" 
   ng-focus="row=3" 
   ng-blur="row=1">
</textarea>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/g5D9QbxqLpusDH5trkY5?p=preview)

Comment: I was wondering if you could explain the expression {{row || '1'}}. I have not seen this previously

Comment: @Barry you could look at the updated answer..with the documenation link I've pasted there.

Comment: It seems like the doc reference is outdated. Information on ng-attr bindings can now be found here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#-ngattr-for-binding-to-arbitrary-attributes

Comment: @user1438038 updated doc reference, thanks for heads up :)